# Correctly crafting routes for asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am struggling to correctly design a DELETE http request in my ASP Web application.

I have the following route defined:

```
    public const string ControllerOnly = "ApiControllerOnly";
    public const string ControllerAndId = "ApiControllerAndIntegerId";
    private const string ControllerAction = "ApiControllerAction";

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var routes = config.Routes;
        // api/projects
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerOnly,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );

        //api/projects/1
        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAndId,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",

            defaults: null,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be all digits
        );

       routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAction,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
   }
```

I am expecting it to hit the following action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int i)
{
    //content remove for brevity
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

In fiddler I try to test using the following: DELETE http://localhost:port/api/controller/1

but that method never gets hit. Instead, the following method is hit:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete()
{
    //content remove for brevity
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

I have a basic understanding of routing but shouldn't that only route I defined ensured that the previous test is successful? 
Note that I have no problem with GET and POST verbs

Any help appreciated

Comment: Do you have any other routes defines? If so, please add them to your post.

Comment: Yes I normally do but since encountering this issue I commented them out to first make this one work. thx

Comment: And why isn't there an action listed in your route? A particular reason?

Comment: I thought in ASP Web Api all that is required is for my methods to start with     GET, POST, DELETE, ... verbs? I have no issue with say, GET api/projects/1

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add the action part in your route as below :-

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: ControllerAndId,
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be all digits);
```

Comment: put your route before default route @user3320502

Comment: when I do remove that dummy parameterless constructor, It's now a 405 method not allowed error I get. I have tried many answers related to that 405 issue and still nothing positive

Answer (score 1):

Add/Register other route-path before default route. It takes always first prior one. So, in your case you need to register one more path in WebApiConfig as below.

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "WithActionApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{Id}", 
                   defaults: new { Id = RouteParameter.Optional 
});
```

**Note :** You must register this route before your default route.
i.e, It should be as below.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "WithActionApi", 
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{Id}", 
                      defaults: new { Id = RouteParameter.Optional 
    });
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: ControllerAndId,
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
       defaults: null,
       constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be all digits
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry the whole route definition is now provided exactly in the order you mention. But still I get nothing.

Comment: Can you put your first route at the end of the method. Your WebApi is taking it as default route. Obviously it is being failed every time.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that although I felt I had put them in the correct order. But just to check I removed all the other routes and It still behaved in the same manner, hitting the parameterless method. thanks

Comment: I think it is the problem with defaults block in route. You are not mentioning that whether id is optional or not. Try to mention it and see.

Comment: I mean to say that "defaults: new { Id = RouteParameter.Optional 
    }" is missing in your registered path.

Comment: In none of my routes do I wish Id to be optional. Where needed It is a requirement. Thanks